# I can only get a file after doing some upload to S3 from AWS using Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, node.js, s3

I was able to upload files by one route, and query them by another. But when I go to consult them as soon as I start the application, before inserting a new file, I get the error
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined`

Below are the codes:

S3 Config

```
const region = process.env.AWS_REGION
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

const S3 = new aws.S3()

S3.config.update({
  region,
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey
});

module.exports = S3
```

Upload Route

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const multerConfig = require('../config/Multer')
const multer = require('multer')

router.post('/file', multer(multerConfig).single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    res.send(key: req.file.key)
})

module.exports = router
```

Multer config

```
const S3 = require('./s3')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
const bucket = process.env.AWS_BUCKET
const acl = process.env.AWS_ACL
const crypto = require('crypto')


module.exports = {
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: S3,
    bucket: bucket,
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    acl: acl,
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) cb(err)
        const fileName = `${hash.toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`
        cb(null, fileName)
      })

    }
  }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 2 * 2048 * 2048,
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const allowedMimes = [
      'image/jpeg',
      'image/jpg',
      'image/png',
      'application/pdf',
    ];
    if (allowedMimes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(new Error('Invalid file type!'));
    }
  }
}
```

Get File Route

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const S3 = require('../config/s3')
const bucket = process.env.AWS_BUCKET

router.get('/:fileName', async (req, res) => {

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: req.params.fileName
    }
    S3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err :>> ', err);
            res.send(err)
        } 
        else {
            res.write(data.Body)
            res.end()
        }
    })

})

module.exports = router
```